# Extending Last Column Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wrote this macro below to check to see if there is a gap between two dates in adjacent columns and then insert columns to fill in that gap.

I want it to be able to run it on as many columns as there are on the worksheet, but, for some reason, DateRange is stuck on the initial size of the worksheet and is not factoring in the additional columns the macro has been adding. I've never had a problem with this before, so I'm stumped!

Anyone out there know what I could do to fix this?

```
Sub weekendsouts()

Dim OUTSDATA As Worksheet, LastColumn As Long, _
DateCell As Range, DateRange As Range

Set OUTSDATA = Worksheets("OUTS DATA")
LastColumn = OUTSDATA.UsedRange.Columns.Count
Set DateRange = OUTSDATA.Range(OUTSDATA.Cells(2, 8), OUTSDATA.Cells(2, LastColumn).Address)

For Each DateCell In DateRange
    With DateCell
        If .Value <> "" Then
            If .Offset(0, 1).Value <> .Value + 1 And .Offset(0, 1).Value <> .Value Then
                .Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
                .EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=.Offset(-1, 1)
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next DateCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You are going to want to use a standard for loop and loop back wards `For  LastColumn to 8 Step -1`

Comment: @ScottCraner second time today this has happened to me. I wrote up my answer before reading your comment honest! I'm going to get a bad rep for this soon :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of way to achieve this, retaining the code you have I would suggest the following alteration, work backwards. When you are working with a collection and adding to it then size of the collection changes but your reference is still linked to the original size. This is the problem you are having.

By working backwards you are not affected by the change in size.

To do this use can use `Step -1` in a loop as per below:-

```
Sub weekendsouts()

Dim OUTSDATA As Worksheet, LastColumn As Long, _
DateCell As Range, DateRange As Range

Set OUTSDATA = Worksheets("OUTS DATA")
    LastColumn = OUTSDATA.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set DateRange = OUTSDATA.Range(OUTSDATA.Cells(2, 8), OUTSDATA.Cells(2, LastColumn).Address)

        For LastColumn = LastColumn to 0 Step - 1 
            'For Each DateCell In DateRange
            Set DateCell = OUTSDATA.Cells(2,LastColumn)
                With DateCell
                    If .Value <> "" Then
                        If .Offset(0, 1).Value <> .Value + 1 And .Offset(0, 1).Value <> .Value Then
                            .Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
                            .EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=.Offset(-1, 1)
                            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Set DateCell = Nothing
        Next    
    Set DateRange = Nothing    
Set OUTSDATA = Nothing
End Sub
```

(This is untested, use as an example to adapt)

What is happening here is that is `LastColumn` was 10 then the loop starts at ten, and the next iteration is till be 9, then 8, etc...

Comment: No problem, If I had given a formula someone just copied and pasted it in an answer with no further explanation I would be mad, but you explained what was said and showed how.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary! This got me on the right track! Never thought to work backwards like that. The only thing is I had to tweak the code a little bit to change all of the `.offset(0,1)` occurrences to `offset(0,-1)` to account for moving backwards.